# Getting error 52 on file check but not save as... what am I missing?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck, I haven't done any VBA in years and I'm not in programming... I've read a whole bunch of stuf about this error and either I'm missing the solution because I don't understand or I haven't found a relevant post, I'm getting nowhere!

Any Ideas as to why the last line of this code returns an error?
Run-time error '52': Bad file name or number

The same variable works fine for Save As later on and the error occurs regardless of the file existing or not.  Also I can't step over the bug, I have to comment it out if that makes any difference, when I try to step over, it just throws up the same error.

Thanks!

```
    Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1
    '
        Dim OldDateRange As Variant
        OldDateRange = Sheets(1).Name

        Sheets("Lookup").Select
        Cells.Find(What:=OldDateRange, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

        Dim NewDateRange As Variant
        NewDateRange = ActiveCell.Value

    Dim NewFile As Variant
    NewFile = "https://mywork.sharepoint.com/xxx/Timesheets/Overtime Approval Forms/Overtime approval form " & NewDateRange & ".xlsm"

    MsgBox (NewFile)

    Dim FileExists As String
    FileExists = Dir(NewFile)
```

Comment: `Sheets(1)` means the sheet on the first tab. if you move it the program might fail. Be aware that the `Find` will start with the cell to the right of `ActiveCell` (`xlByRows`, `xlNext`).What is that `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select` supposed to do? Why are you declaring `NewFile` as `Variant` and then in the next line passing a string to it? Why the parenthesis `()` around `NewFile`. You usually `Dir` a folder, not a file.

Comment: keep in mind that `http://` means it's on the internet... sharepoint in your case, and you cannot write to the internet like that

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info.  I'm aware of the sheet position / name issue thanks, I will make it more robust when it actually works!

Comment: @braX What do you mean by "cannot write to the internet like that"?  There is a Save As command using the exact same path and that works fine.

Comment: hmmm well you must be using a different version than I use then, or you have a sharepoint add-in that handles it. The `Dir()` function in VBA is only intended for local files tho as far as I know. Maybe someone else knows differently.

Comment: Thanks @braX maybe that is the problem, no add-in installed but on latest version of everything.  Possibly the Dir() works differently to the SaveAs.  I'll look at options thanks.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is see if it exists, maybe you can try to download it from that URL, and if the DL succeeds, it must exist. But if the next step would be to delete it if it exists, you are going to get stuck again if you are trying to do this in VBA.

Comment: @braX Ah, you may be on to a winner, I can try opening the file, if it throws an error then the process can continue, if it succeeds then it can close it and report the file already exists.  That would be perfect.  I'll give that a go tonight, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @braX in comments, not a fix to what I was attempting but a different method that should work for me, instead of checking for the file's existence, trying to open the file and using a success to close and report it exists, an error to continue with creation of the new file.  I appreciate this wouldn't work smoothly with particularly large files but it's perfect for what I'm doing.

Comment: Gotta think outside of the box sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the error occurs on the last line of your published code. The reason is that your PC can't identify the drive "https:". The path in your variable `NewFile` isn't mapped on your computer. Therefore the Dir() function can't access it.

As an aside, it's acceptable to use a variable of Variant data type if you don't know which type of data you want to assign to it (although it seems funny that one wouldn't know what one wants) but it's bad practice not to declare a string if a string will be assigned to the variable. The more you leave up to VBA to interpret the greater will be the chance that a mistake is made eventually. Call a spade a spade and no one will try to eat soup with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info.  Yes, the last line of the PUBLISHED code.  It was originally a string but because I was getting this error and I had used a variable in the string to create it, I wondered if that was the cause, I went on a hunt and couldn't find an example of file exist checking that wasn't a defined string written in the code so I thought maybe the issue was with the variable and changed it.  it didn't help!  On the issue of not being able to identify the https drive, how does the save function work then?  The save works fine (it is later in the code).  Thanks

Comment: If `Save` works fine then your issue is with `Dir`. It might be used to determine if the file exists. I think the thing to do is to map the sharepoint to a local drive, and then Dir might work. I'm not sure of either. As an alterantive, skip the test and trap the error on `Save` which would occur if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  The Save As command is what I'm using, to create a new file, it works fine.  There's no error and a new file is created in the on-line folder... or, now I'm thinking that I could trap the error on Save As if the file already exists as that would solve the problem but cause me others...  ok I'll look at doing it there instead.  Thank you!